# Updating table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running my query, but it does not work. The cause is the value of column is null and I'm trying to update it with a integer value.

This is my query.

The default value of `sdoc` is *null*

```
update expenese 
set sdoc = sdoc + '200' 
where expenese.date = '2016-03-26';
```

Comment: What are the **data types** of your columns? Is there a row with a `Date` with that given value? Also: you should try **not** to use reserved T-SQL keywords like `Date` as your column names!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE EXPENESE
SET SDOC=ISNULL(SDOC,0)+200
WHERE DATE='2016-03-26'
```